# $accion = $_REQUEST['accion']; AL EJECUTAR SERVER PHP ME ARROJA ESE ERROR

Tags: php

QUIEN ME PUEDE COLABORAR CON UNA ORIENTACIÓN, ESTO INTENTANDO ENCENDER EL SERVIDOR PARA OBTENER DATOS PERO ME ARROJA ESTE ERROR MI LINEA Y CONDICIONAL LAS VEO APARENTEMENTE BIEN[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Pareciera que no estás enviando la variable accion en tu POST o GET, por eso no la reconoce.

Comment: Nota importante, escribir con mayúsculas es interpretado como gritar. Recuerda que parte importante del funcionamiento de la comunidad es el respeto ya que todos somos voluntarios aquí. Te recomiendo leer las secciones [ask] y [tour]. Saludos!